# Add a screenshot as attachment in Gmail android 5

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, gmail, nexus-5, screenshots, attachments

How can I use a screenshot as an attachment in android 5?
I really don't get why this is so hard, I can only select files from my drive.

To find the screenshot I had to go to Photos -> menu -> device folders -> screenshots (what?)
Here I can't move the image to my drive folder
And no I don't want to enable auto backup for my screenshots
(even if I do I can't find this auto backup folder in my drive)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Gallery app of some sort, locate the screenshot image you want to send. Then there will be a share button and a dropdown list of applications. Find the app that says "Drive" and your image will then be uploaded. From there, you can go to your email app and select your newly uploaded image from your drive for you to send whomever

Comment: when I want to add an attachment, I can only browse my drive folder, I should be able to browse my entire phone, thanks

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of when you're adding attachments

Comment: just found out I can use attach file -> menu (open from) -> photos -> device folders -> screenshots

Comment: Ah yeah that seems like an easier solution.....oh well :D